# C#. Atata Framework. Метод открывающий новую вкладку браузера?

Tags: c#

Хочу написать метод открывающий новую вкладку браузера и юзать там где мне захочется. Подскажите пжлста как написать? Эмулировать нажатие CTRL + T пробовал, не выходит.

Могу открыть новую вкладку вначале теста, это легко:

```
            [SetUp]

            AtataContext.Configure()
                .UseChrome()
                .WithArguments("new tab")
```

Comment: Какой тип приложения у вас?

Comment: Автоматизация. Unit test .net

Comment: Клавиши в Windows можно нажимать через `P/Invoke` метод `SendInput`, вы можете использовать Win32 API? Потом, возможно ли подключить `System.Windows.Input`? (он доступен в WPF) Если да, я могу показать класс с методом для нажимания комбинаций клавиш. Но сработает данный метод только если окно браузера в момент эмуляции активно, а не свернуто, и не в фоне, типа как ввод с клавиатуры получится.

Comment: @aepot, 
_вы можете использовать Win32 API?_
**Думаю да. Проект древний на вэбформах.**

_Потом, возможно ли подключить System.Windows.Input? (он доступен в WPF)_
**Думаю что возможно. Попробую. Спасибо за совет.**

Comment: Мой ответ не помог?

Comment: @aepot, Большое спасибо за помощь. Но примерно в то же время мне ответили на англоязычном stackoverflow. Решил проблему благодаря JavaScript 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/64087330/12326172